# Is there anyway to know the current page when I response the pageshow event in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Now I doing PhoneGap development.
I bind a pageshow event in JS, When my pageA jump to pageB,it will response the JS methods.But how can I get the current page in this event?
for sample:
**pageA -> pageB** , when the pageB displays and I want to know it is pageB and doing something about pageB.If it's pageC and I can doing something about pageC.

Can anyone help?

This is my code:

```
  $("div").live("pageshow",function(e,ui){
           if(page == pageB)
                scroll1.refresh();
            else if(page == pageC)
                scroll2.refresh();

     })
```

Comment: You could extract the url from from the `location.href` and match it against a regex or something. Btw, `live()` is deprecated.

Comment: I use the console.log to show the href and it show the same href no matter which page.

Comment: can you post in your question url in pageA,B and C?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.location.href` to find current url

Comment: I tried your suggest  but it still doesn't work. It show the same href no matter which page.